# How to delete an object from a python list with same value?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list and I want to delete an object of it but there is several object with same value in my list(with deferent indexes )if I want to delete arr8=100 it is going to delete arr2=100
this is my code:

```
q = int(input())
arr = []*200
a,b='+','-'
for i in range(q):
    inp=input()
    if inp.startswith(a):
         if inp[2:5]=='100':
             arr.insert(int(inp[2:5])-1, int(inp[5:]))
         else:
             arr.insert(int(inp[2:4])-1, int(inp[4:]))
             for i in arr:
                 print(i,end=' ')
             print()
     elif inp.startswith(b):
          if int(inp[2:4])>len(arr):
              for i in range(len(arr)):
                  print(arr[i],end=' ')
              print()
          else:
              if inp[2:5]=='100':
                 arr.remove(arr[int(inp[2:5])-1])
              else:
                 arr.remove(arr[int(inp[2:4])-1])
                 for i in range(len(arr)):
                    print(arr[i],end=' ')
                 if len(arr)==0:
                     print('EMPTY',end='')
                 print()
```

input:4 ,+ 1 1,,+ 1 2,+ 1 1,- 3
expect output is:1 2
actual output is:2 1

Comment: Could you please describe the purpose of that code? Please tell us what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your third input `arr` is `[1,2,1]`. Now you enter `- 3` which will result in `arr.remove(arr[int(inp[2:4])-1])` to be evaluated to `arr.remove(1)`, because the last element of arr (`arr[3-1]`) is `1`.

So now you expect the resulting list as `[1, 2]` but what you actual will get is `[2,1]`. That is correct, because what `remove` does is [remove the first item from the list whose value is equal to 1](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). I think what you need is either `del a[2]` or `a.pop(2)`. But with both ways you still got the wrong calculation for your index, so IMHO your line should look like `del arr[int(inp[2:4])-1]`.

As I said in my comment, it would be a lot easier to help you if you exactly describe what you want to achieve, so e.g. it would be much better to use `inp.split()` instead of splices.